# How to transpose a single key-value table in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have. Key-Value table of two columns. I want to get keys as column names and values in individual columns (named as were keys named before). How to do such thing in Postgres ?

Is it possible to get more than one Row for a single key if there were multiple values with same key in original table?

Comment: Please have a look at: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example). And have a look at [all pivot questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+pivot) on PostgreSQL, maybe one comes in handy.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pivot type query and this is usually done using filtered aggregation:

```
select string_agg(value, ',') filter (where key = 'key1') as key_1,
       string_agg(value, ',') filter (where key = 'key2') as key_2,
       string_agg(value, ',') filter (where key = 'key3') as key_3
from the_table;
```

It's **not** possible to make this dynamic.

A fundamental restriction of SQL is that the number, names and types of all columns of a query must be known *before* the query is executed.

---

Depending on how you process the result, aggregating everything into a JSON object might be an alternative:

```
select jsonb_object_agg(key, vals)
from (
   select key, jsonb_agg(value) as vals
   from the_table
   group by key
) t
;
```